# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null. Tried window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

So, I'm relatively new to Javascrip. Though what I want to do is give a moving image on my canvas an id, so that I can ultimately use onclick to use the image as a clickable image, so I can redirect the user to another page, which is what would happen when the image is clicked. Here is my code so far. I need help. If you need any more clarification I will try to explain further.

```
       var ctx;
       var imgBg;
       var imgDrops;
       var x = 0;
       var y = 0;
       var noOfDrops = 50;
       var fallingDrops = [];
           function drawBackground(){
    ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0); //Background
           }
           function draw() {
    drawBackground();

    for (var i=0; i< noOfDrops; i++)
    {
    ctx.drawImage (fallingDrops[i].image, fallingDrops[i].x, fallingDrops[i].y); //The rain drop

    fallingDrops[i].y += fallingDrops[i].speed; //Set the falling speed
    if (fallingDrops[i].y > 1000) {  //Repeat the raindrop when it falls out of view
    fallingDrops[i].y = -25 //Account for the image size
    fallingDrops[i].x = Math.random() * 10000;    //Make it appear randomly along the width
               }

               }
           }
           function setup() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasRegn');

    if (canvas.getContext) {
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                imgBg = new Image();
        imgBg.src = "http://images.susu.org/unionfilms/films/backgrounds/hd/space-jam.jpg";
    setInterval(draw, 36);
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfDrops; i++) {
        // Charles Barkley
        var fallingDr = new Object();
        fallingDr["image"] =  new Image();
        fallingDr.image.src = 'http://xenboards.ignimgs.com/external_data/attachments/8/8795-f09b907a01726a25ca2fbd2f588e3f0e.jpg';
        fallingDr["x"] = Math.random() * 10000;
        fallingDr["y"] = Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDr["speed"] = 3 + Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDrops.push(fallingDr);
        // Bugs bunny
        var fallingDr2 = new Object();
        fallingDr2["image"] = new Image();
        fallingDr2.image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/zN2CSAf.png'
        fallingDr2["x"] = Math.random() * 10000;
        fallingDr2["y"] = Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDr2["speed"] = 3 + Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDrops.push(fallingDr2);
        // Michael Jordan
        var fallingDr3 = new Object();
        fallingDr3["image"] = new Image();
        fallingDr3.image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/XxvJiGg.png'
        fallingDr3["x"] = Math.random() * 10000;
        fallingDr3["y"] = Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDr3["speed"] = 3 + Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDrops.push(fallingDr3);
        // Daffy duck
        var fallingDr4 = new Object();
        fallingDr4["image"] = new Image();
        fallingDr4.image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/QZogw2L.png'
        fallingDr4["x"] = Math.random() * 10000;
        fallingDr4["y"] = Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDr4["speed"] = 3 + Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDrops.push(fallingDr4);
        fallingDr4.image.id = "Daffy";
        }
    }
           }
       setup();
       window.onload = function(){
           document.getElementById("Daffy").onclick=function(){
       alert("Hello World");
       }
       }
```

Comment: You're trying to set the property "onclick" of `document.getElementById("Daffy")`, and getting the error that you cannot set the property "onclick" of null. It's likely that `document.getElementById("Daffy")` is returning null because you have no elements with the ID "Daffy" in your DOM

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fallingDr4.image.onclick=function(){
       alert(this.id);
       }
```

should alert "Duffy".

Comment: I thank you very much, but when fallingDr4 is clicked, still nothing happens

Comment: That's puzzling... That line of code should be put in a place like: 
`var fallingDr4 = new Object();
        fallingDr4["image"] = new Image();
        fallingDr4.image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/QZogw2L.png';
        fallingDr4.image.onclick=function(){
               alert(this.id);
         };
        fallingDr4["x"] = Math.random() * 10000;
        fallingDr4["y"] = Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDr4["speed"] = 3 + Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDrops.push(fallingDr4);
        fallingDr4.image.id = "Daffy";
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to catch the click event on an element that **is not in the document** and hence, not clickable by the user.

When you call `var img = new Image()` a new `<img>` element is created, with all its properties that you can already modify in your javascript. But this element is only available to your scripts, and is not displayed into the page until you call `document.anyElement.appendChild(img)`. So it's better to consider this as an imageObject more than to an element (even if it actually also is).

What is in your document, and accessible to your user, is the `<canvas>` element. So if you want to know if the user has clicked, you will have to attach the `eventListener` to this canvasElement.

But the canvasElement doesn't know what it does represent. When you call `context.drawImage()`, you're just applying the pixels from the imageSource to the ones of the canvas, and all reference to the original imageObject are lost.
To workaround this, you'll then have to store the position of your drawn image into the canvas, and then check if the click event you caught was inside these positions.
Click events' `clientX` and `clientY` properties of the Event passed as arguments of you handler will give you the position of the cursor when the event occurred. But the positions are relative to the top-left corner of the window. So you'll also need to make these relative to the top-left corner of your canvas, which can be done by calling the `getBoundingClientRect()` method of the canvasElement.

Here is a simplified example :

```js
// this function will be called at image's load
var init = function() {
    // a reference to our "in-screen" canvasElement
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // "kitty" will be the js object that will help us know if we clicked on our image
    // "this" refers to the imageObject
    var kitty = {
      width: this.width,
      height: this.height,
      // random positions
      left: Math.random() * (canvas.width - this.width),
      top: Math.random() * (canvas.height - this.height),
    };
    // draw our image at the random positions we created
    ctx.drawImage(this, kitty.left, kitty.top, kitty.width, kitty.height);
    // here we're listening to mousemove event, 
    //  but click event shares the same clientX & clientY properties
    var moveHandler = function(evt) {
      // in the "evt" object passed, we can get the x and y positions relative to the window
      // so we make these relatives to the canvas ones
      var canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = evt.clientX - canvasRect.left;
      var y = evt.clientY - canvasRect.top;

      // now we've got our relative positions, we can check if we were inside the image
      if (x >= kitty.left && x <= (kitty.left + kitty.width) && y >= kitty.top && y <= (kitty.top + kitty.height) ) {
          // we are over the image, do something
          canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        } else {
          canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        }
      };
      // attach this event handler to the canvasElement
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler);
    };

// this will create an imageObject, which will stay "off-screen" (never appendded to the document)
var img = new Image();
// wait that the image has loaded before trying to make any magic
img.onload = init;

img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/70/cats";
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
}
canvas {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

*(you may need to scroll to actually see the image, or go fullscreen)*